# Encrypted shell script is showing in plain text while executing

Tags: command-line, scripts, encryption

[image]I run a encrypted shell script through crontab, while checking for process of script through **ps -ef | grep script_name** it is showing process along with script code in plain text

```
# ps -ef | grep test_script.x

root      5134  2901  0 12:16 pts/3    00:00:00 ./test_script.x -c

#!/bin/bash if [ `echo $?` == 0 ]; then echo "This is my test script"  apt-get update else echo "This is end test script" fi sleep 3    ./test_script.x

root      5164 15802  0 12:16 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto test_script.x
```

Comment: Is it not supposed to decrypt the script before running it?

Comment: It should execute in background only but why it is showing script while checking of process ?

Comment: I am not an expert but I think it's supposed to show the command that is running for that PID?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the encrypted version of the script (the one ending in .x?). Also, ps normally won't show the contents of a shell script, just the name-- could you give us an example of what's happening (redacting sensitive information or creating a separate script for posting purposes)?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. This makes it easier for more people to find and read your question. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: Can other people log in to the computer you are using? Can other other people run `sudo` in the computer you are using? Have other people physical access to the computer you are using? Please consider these aspects of security. See also this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/981812/are-user-files-still-private-when-two-sudo-users-exist-in-ubuntu